# compile hello world to wasm and run in node

Tags: node.js, webassembly

I am trying to run a webassembly module in node.js and I'm getting a `Wasm decoding failedResult`. I think that my problem is transforming the node `Buffer` into an `ArrayBuffer`. Here is my applicable code:

```
fs.readFileAsync( WASM_PATH )
  .then( buf => buf.buffer.slice(buf.byteOffset, buf.byteOffset + buf.byteLength) )
  .then( arrayBuffer => Wasm.instantiateModule(arrayBuffer) )
  .then( results => console.log(results.instance) )
  .catch( err => console.error(err) );
```

I get this error:

```
(relevant details) 

Wasm decoding failedResult = expected version 0c 00 00 00, found 01 00 00 00 @+4
```

When I use `emcc hello_world.c -s WASM=1 -o hello.html` I can load the module and run it in browser. So, I'm pretty sure this is a problem on my end or perhaps some compatibility issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your node version uses an older pre-MVP version of V8 which expects version `0xC`. Your toolchain emits the [now-stable MVP version `0x1`](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webassembly/2017Feb/0002.html).

Node [roughly follows Chrome releases](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/guides/maintaining-V8.md), and [Chrome 57](https://blog.chromium.org/2017/02/chrome-57-beta-css-grid-layout-improved.html) adds support for MVP WebAssembly. That page says the V8 version for Chrome 57 is 5.7.492.65.

Support for MVP is therefore imminent in Node.

Alternatively you could use an older Emscripten toolchain. It would be quite old though: `0xd` was the version prior to MVP (and `0xd` is effectively the same as MVP, modulo the version).